# Nested Volley call takes time to set data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am using `Volley` to make Api call and set data to `RecyclerView`.I have my first  Volley where I get Id field and I use this same Id to make another Api call. I used the response from both api call at same time and set the data to RecyclerView.But the response from second Api call is not set on Recyclerview at same time.Later I manually refresh tab and set data from Database its set.
This is my nested `Volley` Api call

```
private void getData() {
        final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, ApiUrls.FirstCall, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    if (response != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                             CurrentStatusEntry entry = new CurrentStatusEntry();
                            String Id= object.getString("id");
                            id_url = ApiUrls.Info+ Id + "/";
                            JsonObjectRequest foodie_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, id_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                      try {
                                          String name=response.getString("name");
                                          String address=response.getString("address");
                                        entry.setName(name);
                                          entry.setAddress(address);
                                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                }
                            }) 
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(foodie_request, foodie_data_req);
                            current.add(entry);
                            if (current.size() > 0) {
                                adapter = new QueueAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
        }) 
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, restqueue_req);
    }
```

The data from second api call is not set instantly. How to perform this ?